# How to make a SOAP call in PHP?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl

I have to make a SOAP Call on a Axis2 Server with parameters, but I have a lot of problems, I done this on SOAPUI and works fine.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Header>
    <Seguridad>
     <usuario>0000000000</usuario>
      <password>9FDB5D2R4J62755C7DA205S52D8G4H36D4CRCB94978BC40DDD2D4220CB63FE7E</password>
      <fechaSistema>02/01/2015</fechaSistema>
     </Seguridad>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:enviaCONVOL xmlns:ws="http://ws.convol/">
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg0>2014-12-31</arg0>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg1>11:48:46</arg1>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg2>ZmUxMzc3ZDmyYTc3YTAyZjM2YT8lZDc4MzgwOTZhY2Y0YTM1MDg3Wg==</arg2>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <arg3>ZmUxMzc3ZDmyYTc3YTAyZjM2YT8lZDc4MzgwOTZhY2Y0YTM1MDg3Wg==</arg3>
      </ws:enviaCONVOL>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I need do this with soap in PHP and MTOM, and the arg2 is a CID from a zip file.

When I tried to implement the header and send the SOAP call to the server always receive "Internal Error " or "Unknown Content-Encoding". I am having some problems with the headers and the correct implementation of the call, I need to send like the code.

what i get with PHP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://ws.convol/"><SOAP-ENV:Body><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                    <soapenv:Header>
                            <Seguridad>
                         <usuario>0000105847</usuario>
                          <password>9FDBDE265822755C7DA2058053B61580736ECB94978BC40DDD2D4220CB63FE7E</password>
                          <fechaSistema>02/01/2015</fechaSistema>
                         </Seguridad>
                       </soapenv:Header>
                       <soapenv:Body>
                          <ws:enviaCONVOL xmlns:ws="http://ws.convol/">
                             <!--Optional:-->
                             <arg0>2014-12-31</arg0>
                             <!--Optional:-->
                             <arg1>11:48:46</arg1>
                             <!--Optional:-->
                             <arg2>ZmUxMzc3ZDQyYTc3YTAyZjM2YThlZDc4MzgwOTZhY2Y0YTM1MDg3Ng==</arg2>
                             <!--Optional:-->
                             <arg3>ZmUxMzc3ZDQyYTc3YTAyZjM2YThlZDc4MzgwOTZhY2Y0YTM1MDg3Ng==</arg3>
                          </ws:enviaCONVOL>
                       </soapenv:Body>
                    </soapenv:Envelope></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I had this on PHP

```
try{    
    $client=new SoapClient('https://www.convolmiscelaneapruebas.pemex.com/ServiciosCVWEB/ServicioEnviaCONVOLService/ServicioEnviaCONVOLService.wsdl',array( 'trace' => 1, 'exceptions' => 0 ));

    $header = '<SOAP-ENV:Header>
                            <Seguridad>
                         <usuario>0000000000</usuario>
                          <password>9FDBDE265822755C50dHD5D33B61580736ECB94978BC40DDD2D4220CB63FE7E</password>
                          <fechaSistema>02/01/2015</fechaSistema>
                         </Seguridad>
                       </SOAP-ENV:Header>';

    $xml = '<ns1:enviaCONVOL>
                             <!--Optional:-->
                             <arg0>2014-12-31</arg0>
                             <!--Optional:-->
                             <arg1>11:48:46</arg1>
                             <!--Optional:-->
                             <arg2>ZmUxMzc3ZDQyYTc3YTAyZddd5IMKYThlZDc4MzgwOTZhY2Y0YTM1MDg3Ng==</arg2>
                             <!--Optional:-->
                             <arg3>ZmUxMzc3ZDQyYTdnHD90D3185D4MzgwOTZhY2Y0YTM1MDg3Ng==</arg3>
                          </ns1:enviaCONVOL>
                       ';
    $args = array(new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML));    
    $res  = $client->__soapCall('enviaCONVOL', $args);

    echo "<hr>Last Request<br>";
    echo "<pre>", htmlspecialchars($client->__getLastRequest()), "</pre>";


    print_r($res);
}catch (SoapFault $fault){
        echo "SOAPFault: ".$fault->faultcode." - ".$fault->faultstring.' - '.$fault->getMessage();
}
```

I can´t put the Header in the right place...

Comment: What's your question? Can you expand on "lot of problems"?

Comment: When i tried to implement the header and send de SOAP call to the server always receive " Internal Error " or "Unknown Content-Encoding".... I am having some problems with the headers and the correct implementation of the call, I need to send like the code.

Comment: OK. Please also add in the relevant part of the code that returns the result you specify. There is no way it can be answered with the detail thus far provided.

Comment: My real need is do the schema in the code with PHP, but I can´t....

Comment: I should have been more specific - I was hoping you would add the PHP code to your question. I doubt people will be able to replicate the problem unless that code is provided.

Comment: Thanks, I will put the code in the question.

Comment: "I can't put the Header in the right place" - can you expand on that a little more? What do you mean?

Comment: I need to put the header section, in the soap call, but when I try like in the examples, show like that (<SOAP-ENV:Header><ns2:Seguridad><item><key>usuario</key><value>0000105847</value></item>)... I put lke it said in this link http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapheader.php at the end....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used NuSoap

```
$wsdl = "https://www.convolmiscelaneapruebas.pemex.com/ServiciosCVWEB/ServicioEnviaCONVOLService/ServicioEnviaCONVOLService.wsdl";
$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl,TRUE);
$header = 
"<Seguridad>
  <usuario>0000000000</usuario>
  <password>4e671bf08913d677c56359262117c8e67a5507b165f727288a487040bf2a1780</password>
  <fechaSistema>02/01/2015</fechaSistema>
</Seguridad>";
$operation = array('arg0' => '2014-12-31', 
        'arg1' => '11:48:46', 
        'arg2'=>'12095866ae89b7dbcd44640189c57e185918192739040eb52ba5b==',
        'arg3'=>'ZmU5866axMzc3ZDQyJmdAyZjM2YThlZDb7dbcd446401YTM1Mg3Ng=='
        );
$client->setHeaders($header);
$res = $client->call('enviaCONVOL',$operation);
```