# How to set this soap header on a SOAP CALL PHP?

Tags: php, web-services, soap

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
 <Seguridad>
  <usuario>0000000000</usuario>                               
  <password>9FDBDE265822755C50dHD5D33B61580736ECB94978BC40DDD2D4220CB63FE7E</password>
  <fechaSistema>02/01/2015</fechaSistema>
 </Seguridad>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

I need to add this header to the soap call, but, the examples that I found need some namespace, and result so different of this.

Comment: [Your last question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27747005/how-to-make-a-soap-call-in-php), now that it is edited, says "I can't put the Header in the right place". Isn't this post a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used NuSoap.php

```
$wsdl = "https://www.convolmiscelaneapruebas.pemex.com/ServiciosCVWEB/ServicioEnviaCONVOLService/ServicioEnviaCONVOLService.wsdl";
$client = new nusoap_client($wsdl,TRUE);
$header = 
"<Seguridad>
  <usuario>0001250000</usuario>
  <password>4e671bf08913dn8k09d6359262117c8e67a5507b165f727288a487040bf2a1780</password>
  <fechaSistema>02/01/2015</fechaSistema>
</Seguridad>";
$operation = array('arg0' => '2012-08-25', 
        'arg1' => '11:48:46', 
        'arg2'=>'12095866a6l9b7dbcd44640189c57hlZ5918192739040eb52ba5b==',
        'arg3'=>'ZmU5866axMzc3ZDQyJmdAyZjM2YTc57Db7dbcd446401YTM1Mg3Ng=='
        );
$client->setHeaders($header);
$res = $client->call('enviaCONVOL',$operation);
```